# Cannot add ggproto objects together

Tags: r, if-statement, ggplot2, shiny

I'm currently working on an Rshiny app. I had to make multiple boxplots with several select inputs and a checkbox input. I've almost finished my task and now I just need to make it so that every time I change the Species selected, the scale stays the same (unless other variables have been input of course).

My code looks like this:

```
library(shiny)
library(palmerpenguins)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

data <- na.omit(penguins)

colnames(data) <- c("Species",
                    "Island",
                    "Bill Length (mm)",
                    "Bill Depth (mm)", 
                    "Flipper Length (mm)",
                    "Body Mass (g)",
                    "Sex",
                    "Year")

data.numeric <- data[, c(3:6, 8)]

data.categorical <- data[, c(1,7)]


ui <- fluidPage(
  headerPanel("Penguin boxplots"),
  selectInput("ycol", 
              "Numeric Variable", 
              names(data.numeric),
              selected = names(data.numeric)[3]),
  selectInput("xcol",
              "Categorical Variable",
              names(data.categorical),
              selected = names(data.categorical)[2]),
  checkboxInput("split",
                "Split levels by Island",
                value = FALSE),
  selectInput("species",
              "Species Type",
              c("Unspecified", levels(data$Species))),
  mainPanel(
    plotOutput("plot1")
  ))






# 4. Use a select input to allow the user to view separate plotting 
# panels for each species, with each plot panel on the same scale.


server <- function(input, output){
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    par(mar = c(5, 4.1, 0, 1))
    
    if (input$species == "Unspecified"){
      
      
      
      
      if (input$split) {
        ggplot(data, aes(x = data[[input$xcol]], y = data[[input$ycol]], fill = Island)) +
          geom_boxplot(na.rm = TRUE) +
          
          if (input$ycol == "Bill Length (mm)"){
              coord_cartesian(ylim = c(30, 60)) 
          } else if (input$ycol == "Bill Depth (mm)"){
            coord_cartesian(ylim = c(12.5, 21.5)) 
          } else if (input$ycol == "Flipper Length(mm)"){
            coord_cartesian(ylim = c(170, 232)) 
          } else if (input$ycol == "Body Mass (g)"){
            coord_cartesian(ylim = c(2500, 6500))
          } else if (input$ycol == "Year"){
            coord_cartesian(ylim = c(2006, 2009))
          } +
          xlab(input$xcol) +
          ylab(input$ycol) + 
          scale_x_discrete(labels = c("Female", "Male")) +
          theme(text = element_text(size = 15))
        
      } else {
        ggplot(data, aes(x = data[[input$xcol]], y = data[[input$ycol]])) +
          geom_boxplot(na.rm = TRUE) +
          if (input$ycol == "Bill Length (mm)"){
            coord_cartesian(ylim = c(30, 60)) 
          } else if (input$ycol == "Bill Depth (mm)"){
            coord_cartesian(ylim = c(12.5, 21.5)) 
          } else if (input$ycol == "Flipper Length(mm)"){
            coord_cartesian(ylim = c(170, 232)) 
          } else if (input$ycol == "Body Mass (g)"){
            coord_cartesian(ylim = c(2500, 6500))
          } else if (input$ycol == "Year"){
            coord_cartesian(ylim = c(2006, 2009))
          } +
          xlab(input$xcol) +
          ylab(input$ycol) +
          theme(text = element_text(size = 15))
      }
      
      
      
      
      
      
      
    } else {
      
      
      
      
      
      data <- data %>%
        filter(data$Species == input$species)
      if (input$split) {
        ggplot(data, aes(x = data[[input$xcol]], y = data[[input$ycol]], fill = Island)) +
          geom_boxplot(na.rm = TRUE) +
          xlab(input$xcol) +
          ylab(input$ycol) + 
          scale_x_discrete(labels = c("Female", "Male")) +
          theme(text = element_text(size = 15))
        
      } else {
        ggplot(data, aes(x = data[[input$xcol]], y = data[[input$ycol]])) +
          geom_boxplot(na.rm = TRUE) +
          xlab(input$xcol) +
          ylab(input$ycol) +
          theme(text = element_text(size = 15))
      }
    }
    
    
  })
}

















shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The issue arises when I run the lines containing `else if (input$ycol == "Year"){ coord_cartesian(ylim = c(2006, 2009))}` as I get the following error: **Cannot add ggproto objects together. Did you forget to add this object to a ggplot object?**

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong here or if I'm just overlooking some sort of syntax error.

p.s. The code isn't finished - I still need to add more code to control the scales for when the Species is not 'Unspecified', but I'm not doing that until this is figured out.

Comment: Try just `else` in the last ggplot statement instead of `if else`.

Comment: See I thought that before and tried it but it wasn't working. I've changed it back again to that and it's still not working. Still says the same error. Here's the line of code now: 

else { coord_cartesian(ylim = c(2006, 2009))}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simplify things by creating a function that returns the desired `coord_cartesian` statement. The function can then be added to a ggplot chain with `+` as in the usual ggplot workflow.

The example below uses the hard-coded choices in your example. However, if you can provide more information on how these ranges are selected, it may be possible to get the y-range in a more automated way, rather than having to explicitly hard-code each possible case.

In the example below, the `case_when` statement returns the appropriate `ylim` values to feed to `coord_cartesian`. If `input$ycol` does not match any of the options, `case_when` will return `ylim=c(NA,NA)`, which will result in ggplot keeping the default axis range.

```
# I've included only 3 choices. Add in as many additional choices as needed.
coord_fnc = function(x=input$ycol) {
  ylim = dplyr::case_when(
      x=="Bill Length (mm)" ~ c(30,60),
      x=="Flipper Length(mm)" ~ c(170, 232),
      x=="Bill Depth (mm)" ~ c(12.5,21.5)
  )
  coord_cartesian(ylim=ylim)
}


ggplot(data, aes(x = data[[input$xcol]], y = data[[input$ycol]], fill = Island)) +
  geom_boxplot(na.rm = TRUE) +
  coord_fnc() +
  xlab(input$xcol) +
  ylab(input$ycol) +
  theme(text = element_text(size = 15))
```

Try it with the built-in `mtcars` data frame:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(hp, mpg)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  coord_fnc("Bill Length (mm)")
```

[image]

Although the string of `if else` statements takes a lot of code, that approach can work and I'm not sure why you're getting an error (it might be some other part of the code). For example, this works:

```
input = list(ycol = "Year")

ggplot(mtcars, aes(hp, mpg)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  if (input$ycol == "Bill Length (mm)"){
    coord_cartesian(ylim = c(30, 60)) 
  } else if (input$ycol == "Bill Depth (mm)"){
    coord_cartesian(ylim = c(12.5, 21.5)) 
  } else if (input$ycol == "Flipper Length(mm)"){
    coord_cartesian(ylim = c(170, 232)) 
  } else if (input$ycol == "Body Mass (g)"){
    coord_cartesian(ylim = c(2500, 6500))
  } else if (input$ycol == "Year"){
    coord_cartesian(ylim = c(2006, 2009))
  }
```